# Implementing Factory Method Pattern using Spring

Tags: java, spring, factory

I want to understand how the following factory method pattern can be implemented using spring.

Here is the code without using spring

```
interface FileParser {
      void parse()
}   

class XMLFileParser implements FileParser {
     void parse() {
     }
}

class PipeFileParser implements FileParser {
     void parse() {
     }
}

class FileParserFactory {

     FileParser getParserInstance(String fileType) {
     if("XML".equals(fileType)
              return new XMLFileParer();
            else 
              return new PipeFileParser();
  }
}

class ActivityHandler() {

     void handle(String fileType) {
     FileParser fileParer = FileParserFactory.getParerInstance(fileType);
     fileParser.parse();
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a bean FileParserFactory which will be repsonsible for returning new Parsers. 
Additionally this factory bean would have map (fileType => Parser) and a default parser

```
public class FileParserFactory {

 private Map<String, FileParser> fileParsers;
 private FileParser defaultParser;

 FileParser getParserInstance(String fileType) {
 if(fileParsers.containsKey(fileType))
          return fileParsers.get(fileType);
        else 
          return defaultParser;
}
public void setParsers(Map<String, FileParser> parsers) {
   filePaarsers = parsers;
} 

public void setDefaultParser(FileParser parser) {
   defaultParser = parser;
}
}
```

and in code:

`@Inject FileParserFactory factory;`

...

`factory.getParser(fileType);`

I assume that parsers may be reused and that they are thread safe.

This solution is more generic and may be extended if necessarry

Comment: Thanks Michael. With this approach, I would end up instantiating all the parser instances irrespective of whether they are required for that fileType or not right ?                                                         How about the following approach ?  `code`  class FileParserFactory { @Autowired private XMLFileParser xmlFileParser; @Autowired private PipeFileParser pipeFileParser; FileParser getParserInstance(String fileType) {// Code here to determine the right parser}    }`code`

Comment: That's just a matter of your imagination, you can just store list of .class objects and instantiate them on first use.

Comment: ok. I have read a little about factory-method and factory-bean in spring ? Can it be used here ?